# how to configure phpMyadmin on MAC OS?

Tags: macos, phpmyadmin

I have searched on google & try to install phpMyAdmin on MAC OS but I am not getting any proper solution to configure it.

When I write localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/ in browser it is giving error that can't connect or something.

please tell.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the complete error message. What did you do to try to install phpMyAdmin so far?

Answer (score -1):

download a copy Of XAMP. It will install apache server on your local host, where you will find phpmyAdmin.

Make sure you install Xamp and run the services : Apache server , and sql server
Then go to your browser and type:

```
http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/
```

Comment: Thank you but I had implemented with MAMP,as I found some tutorial from google. Now, phpMyAdmin page is loaded but I want to set its username & password so that I can specify in my Rails app. Please give link if you know. Thanks for reply.